# Как установить GridView ниже AppBarLayout

Tags: android, listview, activity, gridview, android-toolbar

Есть данное активити

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/AppBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"/>

     </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <GridView
        android:columnWidth="150dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:gravity="center|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/AppBarLayout"
        android:layout_margin="10dp" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigationView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_navigation"/>
```

У меня GridView отображаеться за Тулбаром т.е 1 и 2 элементы перекрыты им

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне сделать чтоб первый и второй элемент отображались ниже ?

Answer (score 2):

Согласно [en-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30832142/3212712) может помочь вот прописывание вот этого в активити:

```
ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(gridview, true);
```

И добавление поведения для GridView чрез атрибут в разметке:

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```